# Is the function $f\colon{\mathbb{Z}}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}, x\mapsto x+\infty$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Is the function $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}, x\mapsto x+\infty$ continuous?

Here, $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

I am not sure how to answer this question.

Comment: In $\overline{Z}$, how is $-\infty+\infty$ defined and what topology is used, discrete? Well, if the topology is the discrete one, then we don't really need to know how $-\infty+\infty$ is defined. $f$ will be continuous anyway.

Comment: How do you define a metric (or a topology) on $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$? In some extreme cases (say if you use the discrete topology), $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @orole I think I made a mistake and the function should be $f\colon \mathbb{Z}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: @orole If one absolutely had to guess, I think the order topology is the most natural interpretation of the question. In that case, it really does depend on the definition of $-\infty+\infty$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter The order topology is the discrete topology. Shh.

Comment: @orole Not on $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$; in the order topology, $\{+\infty\}$ isn't ~~closed~~ Argh, I mean, open.

Comment: I would interpret $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ as being the two-point compactification of the discrete space $\mathbb{Z}$, with the corresponding topology.  (Which I think would be identical to the order topology.)

Comment: What is the function's value for $0$, $1$, and $2$?  Are they different?

Comment: This depends on how you wish to define $x+\infty$. In measure theory it is often convenient to extend $[0,\infty)$ (the non-negative reals) to $[0,\infty] $ with $\infty=x+\infty=\infty +x$ for all $x\in [0,\infty].$

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to interpret your function to be $f(x)=\infty$.

A constant function is continuous. Why? Consider an open set $O$ in $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$:

- If $O$ contains $\infty$ then its preimage is ${\mathbb{Z}}$, which is an open set by the axioms of topology.
- If $O$ does not contain $\infty$, then its preimage is $\emptyset$, which is an open set by the axioms of topology.

By the definition of a continuous function in topology, $f$ is continuous. We don't need to know anything about the topology on $\bar{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: I think you are right, my (edited) function $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}, x\to x+\infty=\infty$ is continuous.

Comment: But $f$ is no homeomorphism, right? Since it is neither injective nor surjective?

Comment: @Rhjg Yeah $ $ $ $

Comment: Can we extend $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}, f(x)=x+\infty=\infty$ continuously to a function $f'\colon\overline{\mathbb{Z}}\to\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ by setting $f'(-\infty)=\infty$ and $f'(-\infty)=\infty$ and $f'=f$ on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Rhjg Yeah $ $ $ $